# Listview does not bind in static method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I have a listview and I am binding a Listview in static method but when i try to bind the listview then it shows an error prompting that the object reference not set to the instance of the object. when i debug I found that the listview is null. I have a static function like this:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void LoadSearchList(string Locality)
    {
        SearchResults objSearchResults = new SearchResults();
        objSearchResults.LosdBusinessListview(Locality);
    }
    private void LosdBusinessListview(string LocalityName)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchResults objSearchResults = new SearchResults();
            objLocalityMasterDataAccess = new LocalityMasterDataAccess();
            DataTable dt = objLocalityMasterDataAccess.GetLocalitylist(LocalityName);
            ViewState["LocalityID"] = dt.Rows[0]["LocalityID"].ToString();
            objSearchResults.BusinessListingListView.DataSourceID = SearchResultObjectDataSource.ToString();
            objSearchResults.BusinessListingListView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I am calling LoadSearchList() from javascript like this

```
    PageMethods.LoadSearchList(document.getElementById('CityDiv').innerHTML, OnSuccess);
```

I have a list view and its data source like this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="BusinessListingListView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="BusinessListingListView_PagePropertiesChanging"
            DataSourceID="SearchResultObjectDataSource">......</asp:ListView>
         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SearchResultObjectDataSource" runat="server" EnablePaging="true"
            TypeName="CliqueCityDAL.DataAccess.Configuration.YPSearchResultsDataAccess" SelectCountMethod="GetYPSearchResultsCount"
            SelectMethod="GetYPSearchResults" MaximumRowsParameterName="NoOfRows" StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRowIndex"
            OnSelecting="SearchResultObjectDataSource_Selecting">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="searchText" Type="string" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="searchLocation" Type="string" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="searchCategory" Type="string" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SearchLocality" Type="string" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have a selected method of object datasource is like this

```
  protected void SearchResultObjectDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchLocation, searchCategory, searchText;
        searchLocation = Request.Cookies["CityID"].Value;
        searchCategory = Request.QueryString["sc"] == string.Empty ? "" : Request.QueryString["sc"];
        searchText = Request.QueryString["st"] == string.Empty ? "" : Request.QueryString["st"];
        e.InputParameters["searchText"] = searchText;
        e.InputParameters["searchLocation"] = searchLocation;
        e.InputParameters["searchCategory"] = searchCategory;
       if (ViewState["LocalityID"] != null)
       {
           e.InputParameters["SearchLocality"] = ViewState["LocalityID"].ToString();
       }
       else
       {
           e.InputParameters["SearchLocality"] = "0";
       }
    }
```

Comment: where is the code for this object `SearchResultObjectDataSource` being instantiated ?

Comment: I meant could you post that code , Is `SearchResultObjectDataSource` an `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: `SearchResultObjectDataSource` is an ID of datasource and I have added the html code in the question

Comment: Guess you're using the wrong event to populate your `SearchResultObjectDataSource`, Why not try with [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.load(v=vs.110).aspx)